# Attachment is not uploaded in Jira using Oauth

Tags: java, jira, httpclient, multipartform-data

I am trying to upload an attachment in Jira. I successfully did this using basic authentication but when I am trying to upload it using OAuth I got an empty response with 200 status. Please help me on this.

```
 public String uploadFile(List list) throws IOException   {
        String name="admin"+":"+"xyz@123";
         String encodeValue=Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(name.getBytes());
         System.out.println("base64 code :"+encodeValue);

         InputStream stream = (org.glassfish.grizzly.utils.BufferInputStream) list.get(0);

        System.out.println(stream);
         byte [] bytes=IOUtils.toByteArray(stream);
            HttpClient httpClient = HttpClientBuilder.create().build();
            HttpPost postRequest = new HttpPost("https://jirademotest.atlassian.net/rest/api/2/issue/JIR-1/attachments?oauth_nonce=****&oauth_token=*****&oauth_timestamp=***&oauth_signature_method=RSA-SHA1&oauth_consumer_key=hardcoded-consumer&oauth_version=1.0&oauth_signature=***");
            BASE64Encoder base=new BASE64Encoder();
            String encoding = base.encode ("admin:Sarasu@10".getBytes());
            //postRequest.setHeader("Authorization", "Basic " + encoding);
            postRequest.setHeader("X-Atlassian-Token","nocheck");
            MultipartEntityBuilder entity=MultipartEntityBuilder.create();
            entity.addPart("file", new InputStreamBody(stream, (String) list.get(1)));
            postRequest.setEntity( entity.build());
            HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(postRequest);
            HttpEntity entity1 = response.getEntity();
            String responseString = EntityUtils.toString(entity1, "UTF-8");
            //System.out.println(responseString);

            return responseString;
```

Answer (score 0):

The following code works:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.entity.mime.HttpMultipartMode;
import org.apache.http.entity.mime.MultipartEntity;
import org.apache.http.entity.mime.content.FileBody;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;

public class AddAttachmentToIssue {

    public static void main (String args[]) throws IOException
    {
        AddAttachmentToIssue u = new AddAttachmentToIssue();
        u.addAttachmentToIssue("<issue-id>", "<path>");
    }
    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    public void addAttachmentToIssue(String issueKey, String path){


    String auth = new String(org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64.encodeBase64(("username"+":"+"password").getBytes()));
   String  baseURL="https://<jira url>/rest/api/latest/";

    HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(baseURL+"issue/"+issueKey+"/attachments");
    httppost.setHeader("X-Atlassian-Token", "nocheck");
    httppost.setHeader("Authorization", "Basic "+auth);
    System.out.println(httppost);
    MultipartEntity entity = new MultipartEntity(HttpMultipartMode.BROWSER_COMPATIBLE);

    File fileToUpload = new File(path);
    FileBody fileBody = new FileBody(fileToUpload);
    System.out.print(fileBody);
    entity.addPart("file", fileBody);

    httppost.setEntity(entity);
    HttpResponse response = null;
    try {
        response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
        System.out.print(response.toString());
    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    HttpEntity result = response.getEntity();

    if(response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode() == 200)
        System.out.println(response);

    else
        System.out.println("false");

}
}
```

It gives the following response:

```
HTTP/1.1 200  [Date: Mon, 07 Jan 2019 07:01:51 GMT, Server: Apache/2.4.12 (Unix) OpenSSL/1.0.2a, X-AREQUESTID: 121x26602402x1, X-ANODEID: <node -name>, X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block, X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff, X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN, Content-Security-Policy: frame-ancestors 'self', X-ASEN: SEN-5310406, X-Seraph-LoginReason: OK, X-ASESSIONID: 5l5m0z, X-AUSERNAME: <username>, Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, no-transform, Content-Type: application/json;charset=UTF-8, Vary: Accept-Encoding, Set-Cookie: JSESSIONID=<session-id>;path=/jira;Secure;HttpOnly, Set-Cookie: atlassian.xsrf.token=BYHJ-QYVA-BYSV-X6QN|7d0612099e3bb2647d98316c60127e0c9bd9fdee|lin;path=/jira;Secure, Keep-Alive: timeout=5, max=100, Connection: Keep-Alive, Transfer-Encoding: chunked] org.apache.http.conn.BasicManagedEntity@1b485ba
```